# Issue with gcc/g++ while cmake building (./bootstrap)

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, g++, cmake

I decided to reinstall cmake but after removing it I am having an Issues with installing.
After entering a `./bootstrap` It prints I am using type of g++ which I dont know how I got it

```
CMake 3.12.0, Copyright 2000-2018 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc       
C++ compiler on this system is: g++  -std=gnu++1y     
Makefile processor on this system is: make
g++ has setenv
g++ has unsetenv
g++ does not have environ in stdlib.h
g++ has stl wstring
g++ has <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
---------------------------------------------
g++  -std=gnu++1y         -I/home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Bootstrap.cmk   -I/home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Source   -I/home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Source/LexerParser   -I/home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Utilities  -c /home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Source/cmAddCustomCommandCommand.cxx -o cmAddCustomCommandCommand.o
```

and next I am having a couples of this 2 errors during
process:

```
In file included from /home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Source/cmTarget.h:16:0,
                 from /home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Source/cmGlobalGenerator.h:21,
                 from /home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Source/cmAddCustomCommandCommand.cxx:11:
/home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Source/cmAlgorithms.h:175:12: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   cmRange& advance(KWIML_INT_intptr_t amount)
            ^
/home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Source/cmAlgorithms.h:175:39: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘amount’
   cmRange& advance(KWIML_INT_intptr_t amount)
                                       ^
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running make
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /home/luke/cmake-3.12.0/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
```

I see my
[cmake_bootstrap.log](https://pastebin.com/zfMXiK3F) says it should be gnu++11 or gcc+11 :

> error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++
> 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be
> enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler option

Well, I thought there is a easy way to reinstall GNU. But now I see info like:

> **Installing GCC on Unixes:**
>
> GNU Toolchain, including GCC, is included in all Unixes. It is the
> standard compiler for most Unix-like operating systems.

So can you please help me, how can I solve my compiling issues with GNU, so I could proceed CMake installation?

Comment: Why are you trying to bootstrap install cmake from source, when it's available from the Ubuntu repository?

Comment: Because I wanted to recompile cmake to set using libcurl. With command 
'sudo ./bootstrap --system-curl --prefix=/usr/local/' I had issues with installing opencv_contrib modules . Command "make -j7" had faults with downloading through HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I really don't know why, but sudenly I compiled it with `./bootstrap --with-curl --prefix=/usr/local` in diferent repository. But some another scripts are failing with testing and some test says:

> g++ is not enabled by -std=gnu++11 (or -std=c++11).

So some issues still occures. (And I am not able cmake it and compile opencv_contrib on the next step. Which is my main goal)

EDIT:
After I could build ./bootstrap, the last released version in opencv worked for me. The key was just compile cmake with libcurl (using bootstrap) and then make one more completly clear build and compile the last release framework.
[Allready solved]